# C - execution time of program in millseconds using <time.h>

Tags: c, execution

I'm trying to get the execution time of my program using the time header and can't find any resources that simply use `<time.h>` and not `<sys/time.h>`.

I tried

```
 time_t startTime;                
 time_t endTime;                 
 long double execTime;           

 /* Start timer */
 time(&startTime);

 ..STUFF THAT TAKES TIME..

time(&endTime); 
execTime = difftime(endTime, startTime); 

printf("Computing took %Lf\n", execTime * 1000);
```

But this prints out 0 every single time.. I'm guessing because time is an integer and my process takes less than a second.

How can I show execution in milliseconds?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `clock_gettime` should be the preferred way, it is Posix, not standard C. They have only `clock`. It has a lot of disadvantages but is good enough for a quick and dirty measurement.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  int i, j, a[1000000] = { 0 };
  clock_t start, stop;
  srand(0xdeadbeef);
  start = clock();
  // play around with these values, especially with j
  for (j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
      a[i] = rand() % 123;
      a[i] += 123;
    }
  }
  stop = clock();
  printf("Time %.10f seconds\n", (double) (stop - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I multiplied the output by 1000 to get milliseconds and I'm good.

Comment: Although the MSVC implementation of `clock` does give **wall time** as [stated here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30.aspx)

Comment: @deamentiaemundi this worked on an online compiler but once I brought into the server in which the professor will compile it in.. it returns 0.000 milliseconds every time. Weird

Comment: @Walker Weird, indeed. Did you use the exact code I posted? Did you trie to add a zero or two to the upper limit of `j`? The inner loop can't be optimized because of the `rand`, at least it shouldn't, so...mhmm...

Comment: @deamentiaemundi I thought that code between the start and stop were simply tasks that take time. As in it gets replaced with my task. It sounds like they're not? Thanks for your help man

Comment: @Walker Uh, sorry, thought you tried mine. `clock` is simple and easy but one of the many disadvantages is  the medium-only resolution. Milliseconds are OK but anything less needs other methods, like e.g.: `clock_gettime`. Or use internal CPU-counters ( e.g.: the rtdsc counter) but that is not very easy now, in the time of multiprocessor architectures.

Comment: `clock()` precision varies among operating systems and C libraries: on Linux it seems to be rather coarse, but on Mac OS X, it has microsecond precision.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to measure time is to use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts_current);`.

Also, [`gettimeofday()` should be avoided](https://blog.habets.se/2010/09/gettimeofday-should-never-be-used-to-measure-time).

A complete example of using `clock_gettime()` to measure time difference (both seconds and nanoseconds, which you could convert to milliseconds):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

struct timespec diff(struct timespec start, struct timespec end)
{
    struct timespec temp;
    if ((end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec)<0) {
        temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec-1;
        temp.tv_nsec = 1000000000+end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec;
    } else {
        temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec;
        temp.tv_nsec = end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec;
    }
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    struct timespec time1, time2;
    int temp = 0;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);
    for (int i = 0; i< 242000000; i++)
        temp+=temp;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time2);
    printf("Time difference: %ld [s] %ld [ns]", (long) diff(time1,time2).tv_sec, (long) diff(time1,time2).tv_nsec);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `clock_gettime()` is not available on Mac OS X, so it is not as portable as `gettimeofday()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `time` function only has 1 second resolution.  Instead, use `gettimeofday` which has microsecond resolution.

```
struct timeval tstart, tend;
gettimeofday(&tstart, NULL);
// do something that takes time
gettimeofday(&tend,NULL);
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample? Thank you so mucj

Comment: `gettimeofday` should not be used for measuring time difference. Use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts_current);` instead, if you want to know more, please [check this out](https://blog.habets.se/2010/09/gettimeofday-should-never-be-used-to-measure-time)

Comment: `gettimeofday` is unix specific, use `clock()` for a quick and dirty portable solution.